# external fonts (@font-face) doesnt work with firefox

Tags: css, firefox

here is my code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('websymbols-regular-webfont.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

here is my header file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontstylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Are you font files located in the css folder like your links suggest? Please also show the font-family css you are using to call the font-face.

Comment: @BillyMoat i have answered this question my self ... i just posted it for every one to try my solution .. (which is working already)

Comment: Your solution appears to be "I had to make sure my fonts CSS was linked last". There's no reason this should generally be the case, as far as I know, so it's not especially useful without more context.

Comment: @Chowlett , "I had to make sure my fonts CSS was linked last" simple when you read it , hard when you have it ..

Answer (score 0):

Check the font files path. if you put the fonts in separate font folder out side the css folder mean mentioned the font pack path in css and try it work fine..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```